# Test route dispatch

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, phpunit, mockery

I have an API with a scenario that forwards a request onto another controller.

ie:

```
$request = Request::create'/new/resource', 'POST');
Route::dispatch($request);
```

How would I write a test to verify this dispatch happens as I expect? (I know I'm not supposed to mock the 'Request' facade)

ie:

```
class MyTest extends TestCase {
    public function myTestShouldForwardRequestCorrectly()
    {
        // Once for initial request, and once for fwd request?
        // Maybe also test w/ mockery spy which resource the Request is going to?
        $m = Route::shouldReceive('dispatch')->times(2);

        .... setup test ...

        $this->call('POST', '/initial/resource', $parameters);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to mock Request - just verify that it is beeing sent. Dispacth will be verified upon controller action. When you call:

```
$this->call("POST","/path",$params);
```

You are triggering route collection which act as a **lookup table**. That collection is storing all predefined routes. So you will have to hook into that collection, to verify your own dispatch. Whole response process ih handled by **TTPKernelInterface**, and act like a stack - which returns response to user.  To test, you will have to do a lot of mocking, because of dependencies. You may take a look at core Laravel tests directory. There you can find how Taylor Otwell tested whole framework without application - by simulating request. I learned a lot from there.